# Проверка совместимости приложения с версиями Android

Tags: веб-служба, сервисы, android

Есть ли какой-нибудь сервис для проверки совместимости приложения с различными версиями Android?

У меня нет аккаунта разработчика в Google Play

Comment: Google Play Developer Center?

Answer (score 5):

Вас интересует проверка работоспособности именно на различных версиях Android или же на различных устройствах различных производителей?

Если первое, то с этим вполне успешно справляется тот же LINT, входящий в состав SDK.

Если же второе, то существует уже немалое число сервисов, готовых предоставить вам готовую ферму разнообразных девайсов от большинства известных производителей для автоматического тестирования вашего приложения. Первое, что вспомнилось:

- [AppThwack](https://appthwack.com/)
- [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing.html)
- [TestDroid](http://testdroid.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте все версии андроид в AVD и тестируйте вручную, если вам это нужно. Ну, или виртуальная машина + Android x86 разных версий. Алгоритм тот же, всё руками. Или как товарищ выше говорил - пользуйтесь уже существующими сервисами для тестирования.